# How to slowly draw a line in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, draw

I want to slowly draw a line in python so the act of drawing is actually visible to the naked eye.

I tried making it by putting it in a loop and increasing the distance each time but i never had any success with it. The thing is nothing would appear for 3 sec and then the whole line would appear which is the opposite of what i want to accomplish. I didn't have success with a `pygame.display.delay()` function either. The only thing that kind of worked is having clock.tick set to some abysmal values such as `clock.tick(300000)` but this would just make the entire program really laggy.

```
def draw_red_line(i):
    y = 0
    while y < 300:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, (i*100+50, 0), (i*100+50, y))
        y+=0.01
```

Comment: @TomaszBartkowiak Result looks similar to how **delay** works, it stops the program and even seems to crash it. Even if it worked i would try to avoid terminating the entire program just for this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a sleep is not a good idea in this sort of situation, since it slows the whole thread (which is the entire program in a single-thread model).

It's better to keep some kind of state information about the line, and based on real-time timings (e.g.: elapsed milliseconds) progress the "growth" of the line, second by second.

This means the line needs to be broken into segments, and the smallest line segment is a single pixel.  Using the [Midpoint Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), is an efficient way to determine all the pixels that lay on a line.  Once all the "line parts" have been determined, it's possible to simply update the end-point of the line based on the elapsed time.

Here's some code I wrote earlier that, given a pair of points, returns a list of pixels.

`midpoint.py`:

```
def __plotLineLow( x0,y0, x1,y1 ):
    points = []
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    yi = 1
    if dy < 0:
        yi = -1
        dy = -dy
    D = 2*dy - dx
    y = y0

    for x in range( x0, x1 ):
        points.append( (x,y) )
        if D > 0:
           y = y + yi
           D = D - 2*dx
        D = D + 2*dy
    return points

def __plotLineHigh( x0,y0, x1,y1 ):
    points = []
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    xi = 1
    if dx < 0:
        xi = -1
        dx = -dx
    D = 2*dx - dy
    x = x0

    for y in range( y0, y1 ):
        points.append( (x,y) )
        if D > 0:
            x = x + xi
            D = D - 2*dy
        D = D + 2*dx
    return points

def linePoints( pointA, pointB ):
    """ Generate a list of integer points on the line pointA -> pointB """
    x0, y0 = pointA
    x1, y1 = pointB
    points = []
    if ( abs(y1 - y0) < abs(x1 - x0) ):
        if ( x0 > x1 ):
            points += __plotLineLow( x1, y1, x0, y0 )
        else:
            points += __plotLineLow( x0, y0, x1, y1 )
    else:
        if ( y0 > y1 ):
            points += __plotLineHigh( x1, y1, x0, y0 )
        else:
            points += __plotLineHigh( x0, y0, x1, y1 )

    return points


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #midPoint( (597, 337), (553, 337) )
    print( str( linePoints( (135, 295), (135, 304) ) ) )
```

And some demonstration code which implements a `SlowLine` class.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import sys

from midpoint import linePoints  # Midpoint line algorithm

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 400

SKY_BLUE = ( 30,  30,  30)
SKY_RED  = (200, 212,  14)

# Global millisecond count since start
NOW_MS = 0

class SlowLine():
    def __init__( self, pixels_per_second, x0,y0, x1,y1, colour=SKY_RED ):
        self.points       = linePoints( ( x0, y0 ), ( x1, y1 ) )
        self.pixel_count  = len( self.points )
        self.speed        = pixels_per_second
        self.start_point  = self.points[0]     # start with a single-pixel line
        self.end_point    = self.points[0]
        self.pixel_cursor = 0                  # The current end-pixel
        self.last_update  = 0                  # Last time we updated
        self.colour       = colour
        self.fully_drawn  = False

    def update(self):
        global NOW_MS

        if ( self.fully_drawn == True ):
            # nothing to do
            pass
        else:
            # How many milliseconds since the last update() call?
            if ( self.last_update == 0 ):
                self.last_update = NOW_MS
                time_delta = 0
            else:
                time_delta = NOW_MS - self.last_update
                self.last_udpate = NOW_MS

            # New pixels to add => speed * time
            new_pixel_count = time_delta * self.speed / 1000   # this may loose precision with very small speeds

            if ( new_pixel_count + self.pixel_cursor > self.pixel_count ):
                # We're out of pixels
                self.end_point  = self.points[-1]   
                self.full_drawn = True
            else:
                # Grow the line by <new_pixel_count> pixels
                self.pixel_cursor += new_pixel_count
                self.end_point     = self.points[ int( self.pixel_cursor ) ]

    def draw( self, screen ):
        pygame.draw.line( screen, self.colour, self.start_point, self.end_point )




### MAIN
pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Slow Line Movement")


# Create some random lines
lines = []
for i in range( 20 ):
    rand_speed = random.randint( 1, 50 )
    rand_x0    = random.randint( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH )
    rand_y0    = random.randint( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT )
    rand_x1    = random.randint( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH )
    rand_y1    = random.randint( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT )
    lines.append( SlowLine( rand_speed, rand_x0, rand_y0, rand_x1, rand_y1 ) )


# Main event loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:
    NOW_MS = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # Update the line lengths
    for l in lines:
        l.update()

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        print("down")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        print("left")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        print("right")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_q] and ( keys[pygame.K_RCTRL] or keys[pygame.K_LCTRL] ) ):
        print("^Q")
        done = True

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    WINDOW.fill( SKY_BLUE )
    for l in lines:
        l.draw( WINDOW )

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

In this animation the progress is a bit jerky, but that's the animation, not the demo.
[image: slow_lines.gif]

Answer (score 2):

You must [`display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) to update the display **and** let the window events to be processed using [`event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

```
def draw_red_line(i):
    y = 0
    while y < 300:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, (i*100+50, 0), (i*100+50, y))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.event.get()
        y+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a drawing visible on the screen you've to update the display (e.g. [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)), and you've to handel the events by either [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) or [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).
Also note that the parameters for [`pygame.draw.line`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) must be integral. Use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to convert a floating point value to an integral value.

Drawing the line in a loop and refreshing the display doesn't do what you want because the line is drawn without delay. I do not recommend creating animations in a separate loop within the main application loop. Use the application's main loop to draw the line.

Create a function that can draw a line from a `start` point to an `end` point, dependent on a value p in range [0.0, 1.0]. If the value is 0, no line is drawn. If the value is 1, the full line is drawn. Otherwise part of the line will be drawn:

```py
def draw_red_line(surf, color, start, end, w):
    xe = start[0] * (1-w) + end[0] * w
    ye = start[1] * (1-w) + end[1] * w
    pygame.draw.line(surf, color, start, (round(xe), round(ye)))
```

Use this function in the main application loop:

```py
w = 0
while True:
    # [...]

    draw_red_line(window, (255, 0, 0), line_start[i], line_end[i], w)
    if w < 1:
        w += 0.01
```

See also [Shape and contour](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_draw_shape_and_contour.md)

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300,300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

line_start = [(100, 0),   (200, 0),   (0, 100),   (0, 200)]
line_end   = [(100, 300), (200, 300), (300, 100), (300, 200)]

def draw_red_line(surf, color, start, end, w):
    xe = start[0] * (1-w) + end[0] * w
    ye = start[1] * (1-w) + end[1] * w
    pygame.draw.line(surf, color, start, (round(xe), round(ye)))

count=0
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)

    for i in range(int(count)):
        draw_red_line(window, (255, 255, 255), line_start[i], line_end[i], 1)
    if count < 4:
        i = int(count)
        draw_red_line(window, (255, 0, 0), line_start[i], line_end[i], count-i)
        count += 0.01
    else:
        count = 0
        
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: This solution helped me understand the problem better, but another problem emerged: I have other lines being drawn in a program that should work as sort of a "field". '''pygame.display.flip''' messes with this lines as well and i want them to remain static.

Comment: @dzi Sorry, but I can't "see" your current code. So I can guess only. Possibly you need a list of `ly` (e.g. `ly = [0] * N`, where N is the number of lines). Increment `ly[i]` if it is less than 300 (e.g. `if ly[i] < 300: ly[i] += 0.5`)